# Normal series of finite nonsolvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732446/a-problem-in-non-solvable-group). I got interested in the problem presented, so I tried to solve it.
The problem is:

> If $G$ is a finite non-solvable group, then $G$ has a normal series $1\unlhd N\lhd H\unlhd G$ such that $H/N$ is a direct product of isomorphic non-abelian simple groups.

My attempt goes as follows.

> If $G$ is simple, we're done. Otherwise, $G$ has a nontrivial normal
> subgroup, and a minimal one (I'm not sure this is hypothesis is
> needed, my reasoning was that if it's minimal then there are more chances of it being simple) between them, say, $H'$. If $H'$ is simple and nonabelian
> we're done, since we can take $N=1$ and $H=H'$. If $H'$ is abelian
> then $H'$ is solvable and $G/H'$ is not solvable (Otherwise $G$ would
> be solvable).
>
> In this case we apply induction to $G/H'$: There is a normal series $1\trianglelefteq N/H'\trianglelefteq H/H'\trianglelefteq G/H'$ such that
> $(H/H')/(N/H')$ is a direct product of isomorphic nonabelian simple groups.
>
> But by the third isomorphism theorem $(H'/H)/(N/H)=H'/N$.
>
> So you can take the normal series $1\trianglelefteq N\trianglelefteq H\trianglelefteq G$ as given.
>
> If $H'$ is nonabelian, not simple, but solvable, the reasoning above
> works; if it's still not solvable, by induction there is a normal
> series
>
> $$1\trianglelefteq N\trianglelefteq H\trianglelefteq H'$$ such that
> $H/N$ is a direct product of isomorphic nonabelian simple groups.

I don't think the last part will go well; the given normal series is not necessarily normal in $G$. If those subgroups were characteristic in $H'$ we'd be done but the choice of $H'$ prevents that from happening.

So I'm thinking I should change the choice of $H'$.

If we take $H'$ to be maximal instead, we don't get a lot. In this case $G/H'$ is simple. If $H'$ is solvable then $G/H'$ is simple nonabelian and we're done. Otherwise we're in the same situation, only that in this case $H'$ might have proper characteristic subgroups (This is still not always the case, for example $A_5$ in $S_5$).

Comment: I don’t know if it matters, but are you assuming that your group is finite?

Comment: Yes. I assume that the group is finite.

Comment: Then please add the information.

Comment: One way to do it is the following: take $N$ to be the soluble radical (that is, the maximal soluble normal subgroup), and then $H/N$ to be a minimal normal subgroup of $G/N$. (I'll let you fill in the details.)

Comment: Ok. I had thought I might use the Fitting subgroup, but since we have cases in which it's trivial (the same as the radical) I had thought it wouldn't work. But yes, I'll try using the radical.

Comment: This depends on the result that a characteristically simple group (i.e. one that has no proper nontrivial characteristic subgroups) is a direct product of isomorphic copies of a simple group. This is a standard but moderately difficult result.

Comment: @verret But you have left the most difficult part of the problem, showing that $H/N$ is a direct product of isomorphic simple groups, as details to be filled in.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sure, it was just a hint to get the OP started...

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, now that I remember, I think I've used that result before (years ago, when I was working on my bachelor thesis). Using it, since a minimal normal subgroup is characteristically simple, then $H/N$ is indeed a direct product of isomorphic copies of a simple group. I'll work on the details. In particular, the unlucky case in which this simple group ended up being abelian I don't know if that can happen, but even if it can, I think that case is one of the ones I could solve above.

Comment: @DavidMolano: If that simple group ended up being abelian, then it would be solvable, contradicting the assumption that $n$ is the soluble radical.

Comment: Oh, of course. That's it.